# How does one correctly format command line arguments?

Tags: c, command-line, cs50, argv

I am trying to construct a simple programme to acquaint myself with command line functionality, I seem to have formatted something incorrectly, but I find it very difficult to understand precisely what the resulting error message means. My intenion is to create a programme which checks that all the characters in the command line are digits. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv); i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(argv[i]))
        {
            printf("Please provide letters or numbers only");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Success!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I receive when I attempt to compile is: `c:9:32: error: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'const char *'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`.

Comment: Learn about pointers to pointers first . `argv` is one of those but you seem to be trying to use it as if it is a pointer to char

Comment: `argv` is not a `char *`.  Try `i < argc` and `strlen(argv[i])`.  You will want to iterate of the characters in `argv[i]`.

Comment: You need nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the arguments, and the inner loop iterates over the characters in that argument. The outer loop should start at `argv[1]`.

Comment: This turned into an absurd example of obfuscated code!  Sometimes such things are useful as a curiosity: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { (void)argc; for( const char *a = *++argv; a && (*a || ((a = *++argv) && *a)); a++ ){ if( !isalnum(*a) ){ fprintf(stderr, "Invalid char '%c'\n
", *a); return EXIT_FAILURE; } } return 0; }`

Comment: Before it even looks at `argv` a program should check `argc` to find out how many arguments were passed. That is what it is for. Even in one's own work, it is ridiculously easy to pass no arguments by mistake, and then the program will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` is an array (pointer) of pointers to strings.

`isalnum` is checking a character, not a whole string, so you will need two loops: to check each strings and to check each characters in the strings.

This code won't get the warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    for (int c = 1; c < argc; c++) // loop for checking each strings
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[c]); i++) // loop for checking each characters in the strings
        {
            if (!isalnum(argv[c][i]))
            {
                printf("Please provide letters or numbers only");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Success!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you may want this code with implovements:

- Print the message only once instead of for each characters.
- Use `size_t` for looping until the length of the string.
- Call `strlen()` once before the loop instead of calling in each iteration.
- Use `puts` instead of `printf` to print newline character at the end of output.
- Add `return 0;` to clarify that the code returns 0.
- Remove unnecessary `#include`s, including non-standard one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int all_ok = 1;
    for (int c = 1; c < argc; c++)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(argv[c]);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            all_ok = all_ok && isalnum(argv[c][i]);
        }
    }
    if (!all_ok)
    {
        puts("Please provide letters or numbers only");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Success!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, sorry it has taken me a while to confirm this answer!